# Problems with re-registering plugin in Dynamics 2011

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a problem with registering a plugin in Dynamics CRM 2011.

I have updated a registered plugin and re-registered it in the database (using the Plugin Registration tool, which reports a successful re-register). Upon running the plugin, the previous code, not the latest code, is being run.

How can I check that the plugin is successfully registered, or what else could be going wrong here?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Nut sure if you updated your plugin or deregistered and registered again.
However a common practice is to increment the assembly version before you update the plugin:

[image: CRM Plugin Assembly version]

Comment: hi, thanks but I did try this. Usually we re-register without doing this and it works fine.

Comment: It might usually work, but 100% can cause issues like you are seeing if you don't increment the version number or do an IISReset and possibly an Async service restart (depending on the type of plugins you have)

Comment: hi, yes I've done the iisreset and restarting services, etc. I've tested with other plugins and they update ok, it's just this one that seems to not be updating properly.

Comment: Solved this. Also removing the assembly from the GAC was needed before re-registering.

Comment: Presumably you were choosing GAC as the store options when registering the assembly with the plugin tool?